# Get SharePoint list id from a SharePoint Drive item

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the SharePoint list id from a drive item data.

I know the opposite way is is possible with
 `GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem`

For example I'm using the enpoint `GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')`
To search for files and folders within a SharePoint drive. This search returns details for the drive item. If a file exists I would like to update the corresponding list item, but I can't find a way to extract the list id for a drive Item data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand `listItem` property of `driveItem`

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/driveItem?$expand=listItem
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?$expand=listItem
```

Resource:

[driveItem relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships)